# How can I get the url working from js html builder in Django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-urls

I am currently building a web app using Django.
I've build a calendar using JS and I am building HTML basically from the Js File.

I am trying to include hrefs in each calendar day. For example :
{% url 'calendarDay' day=28 month=12 year=2016 %} is what should have for 28/12/2016 date.

If I try to go to this url from anywhere else in my templates it works. For some reason it is not working when I pass the html from js.

This is what I have in my urls:

```
url(r'^calendar/$', views.calendar, name='calendar'),
url(r'^calendar/(?P<day>\w+)/(?P<month>\w+)/(?P<year>\w+)/$',views.calendar, name = 'calendarDay'),
```

This is my js builder function (the part that builds the previous month's days):

```
    if (FirstDay.getDay()==0){
        for (var i=LastMonthDays-5; i <= LastMonthDays; i++) {
          href="<a href=\"{% url 'calendarDay' day="+i+" month="+(pastMonth.getMonth()+1)+" year="+pastMonth.getFullYear()+" %}\">"
          html +=href+ "<li>"+(i)+"</li></a>";
        }
    }
```

This is how the html file looks like when I inspect the page:

```
<a href="{% url 'calendarDay' day=28 month=12 year=2016 %}"><li>28</li></a>
```

For some reason the urls that it gets is:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/calendar/%7B%%20url%20'calendarDay'%20day=28%20month=12%20year=2016%20%%7D

And ofcourse I get the following error:

The current URL, calendar/{% url 'calendarDay' day=28 month=12 year=2016 %}, didn't match any of these.

What might be the issue here?

Comment: DTL doesn't work in JS files.... because they're not a template.

Comment: But it is passing the html code into the template. If I inspect the file I get what I should get

Comment: No, its passing the html code into the rendered html

Comment: How can this be implemented elsewise? Because the whole calendar html file is rendered from here.

Answer (score 0):

Templatetags will be rendered in server side, before javascript. you should create a javascript function for generating your calendar urls.